# How to correct an existing DocuSign envelope to add a document to it with their C# SDK?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have an existing envelope with a document in it. This document has a fixed number of places to sign built in. If we think we need more places to sign, we have an additional document dedicated to just that.

I can create the envelope with the additional signatures document if we know we're going to have that many signatures from the beginning. But I'm unsure how to add the document to an existing, not yet complete, envelope for situations where new signers come on-board after the first signature is received. I'd like to not have to require those that have already signed to sign again, so it sounds like I need to correct the envelope.

Their REST documentation seems to have exactly what I'm looking for with [UpdateDocument](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/). I'm using the C# SDK and it seems to have [a similar function](https://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-csharp-client/class_docu_sign_1_1e_sign_1_1_api_1_1_envelopes_api.html#a1ae97f5de6ec13a0a77ed35db17e388f) except with no place to actually put the document's Base64 bytes.

Is it possible to use the C# SDK to append a document to an existing, incomplete envelope?

Answer (score 0):

It currently seems impossible to use the C# SDK for this as the UpdateDocument function has an open bug for this exact reason (no place to specify document bytes that would go in the request body): https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client/issues/357